# Trouble installing Ambethia Recaptcha in Rails 2.3.15

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, recaptcha

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide! I'm running a Rails site (Rails 2.3.15 / Ruby 1.8.7) and trying to install ambethia Recaptcha. My understanding is that this version is still good for Rails below 3:

https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha/blob/96e237ecb60414ce27252f9a272e10951f323eab/README.rdoc

and

`config.gem "recaptcha", :lib => "recaptcha/rails", :version => "0.3.2"`

I tried installing this version in two different ways. First, I pasted the config.gem line above into my environment.rb file. It gave me a long error message with warnings similar to the below:

`Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.`

At the end was this message:

`Missing these required gems: recaptcha = 0.3.2 You're running: ruby 1.8.7.352 at /opt/local/bin/ruby18 rubygems 1.8.19 at /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8, /home/goseecampus/.gem/ruby/1.8 Run`rake gems:install`to install the missing gems.`

Second attempt: I took the code out of environment.rb. Then, I tried to install the gem using the readme file's instructions. My SSH input:

`config.gem "ambethia-recaptcha", :lib => "recaptcha/rails", :source => "http://gems.github.com", version => "0.3.2"`

It resulted in an error as well:

`-bash: recaptcha/rails,: No such file or directory`

I really appreciate any help you can provide for resolving this issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `rake gems:install`, with the first line in your `environment.rb`.

The second line is not a shell command, but a snippet of ruby meant for your app's configuration in `environment.rb`. It's the same as the first, but for an older version of the gem.

To install a gem on the command line, you would use `gem install recaptcha --version 0.3.2`. You are still going to need the first line in your `environment.rb` config, and should just let rake install the gems for you though.

Edit:

A quick look on [rubygems.org](https://rubygems.org/gems/recaptcha/versions) tells me `0.3.2` wasn't published, and would need to be installed from git. Try `0.3.1` instead.

Comment: Thanks, Jason. I ran into trouble, though. First, I edited enviroment.rb by adding `config.gem "recaptcha", :lib => "recaptcha/rails", :version => "0.3.2"`. Then, I restarted my app, logged in via SSH, and tried `rake gems:install`. The response: `rake aborted! No Rakefile found`. I thought the problem might be that I hadn't done `su admin`. When I try the command as admin, I get `bash: gem: command not found`. Finally, I tried doing `gem install recaptcha --version 0.3.1`. The response: `You don't have write permissions into the /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8 directory.` What should I try next?

Comment: `rake aborted! No Rakefile found` Usually means you're not in the root directory of the project. This is pretty basic Rails stuff, not specific to the `recaptcha` gem. But, you're working with such an old version of Rails, it's probably hard to find accurate information for what you're trying to do.

I'd suggest looking at these [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/) for the 2.3 branch of rails, it will cover most of the basics for you, in particular maybe the section on the Rails command line tools.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, Jason. I'm stuck on a project, but when I shake free I'll do some research using the link you provided.

Comment: all i did was specify gem 'recaptcha, '0.3.1' worked like a charm for me. had some other require issues but they were easy to resolve